# Icloud problem on my ipad

Tags: icloud, ipad

I have an ipad 2 and its just 2nd hand. My ipad 2 had been reset and then when I open it up it says that I need to connect/sign in to an Icloud account while I dont have one. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the previous owner left the Activation Lock turned on. You will need to turn the device off and then the pre-owner can turn it off via iCloud.com

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365

Answer (score 0):

First of all (just in case you have one and didn't know), if you have an iTunes account, you have an iCloud account.  If that's not the case, you could make one, which is free, easy, and takes almost no time.  Is it setup that is asking for an account or an app?